# Calculate $\int_{-1-i}^{2-i} e^{-t^2}dt$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate
$$\int_{-1-i}^{2-i} e^{-t^2}dt$$
Obviously, this integral can not be solved in closed form. However it can be expressed in terms of special functions, as $\operatorname{erfc}$ but the presence of $-i$ in the integration extremes disorients me.

**Edit.** My approach:

We have
$$\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$$
i.e.
$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\operatorname{erf}(x)$$
Since
$$\int_{-1-i}^{2-i}=\int_{0}^{2-i}-\int_{0}^{-1-i}$$
Therefore
$$\int_{-1-i}^{2-i} e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\left(\operatorname{erf}(2-i)-\operatorname{erf}(-1-i)\right)$$

Comment: The error function exists with complex arguments.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you. Then I revise the post with my attempt at a solution.

Comment: @Lucas, Because this is the process that has occurred to me but, I confess, that I have a lot of experience on these issues. Can you write your proceedings, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is now to evaluate the result. Wikipedia page shows that $$\text{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\,n!}$$which holds for every complex number $z$.

Now, working the the complex arguments is not the most pleasant thing to do. Just for fun, I limited the summation to $n=12$ and obtained for your result $$\frac{398718863579411}{192752239680000}+\frac{339579173 }{1862784000}i$$ which is $\approx 2.06856+ 0.182297 i$ while using the error function, it would be $\approx 2.05583+ 0.178763 i$.

I hope and wish someone would provide a better and more based answer.